# How to check amount is greater than 100 after clicking button

Tags: java, android

**Main Activity**
i want to check the amount is greater than 100 , after clicking button

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    buyItemButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (amount_checker >= 100){
                Intent intent = new Intent(CartActivity.this,AddressActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("itemList", (Serializable) itemsList);
                startActivity(intent);
               }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+amount_checker, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }

            }
       });
}
```

**i want to get the amount checker value to go to oncreate function**

```
private void calculateAmount() {
       
        amount_checker = 1223.00023223; 
    }
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to do. You are checking the value. What is it that you don't know how to do? Calculate amount_checker?

Comment: It's not clear.please explain what amount-checker is and tell us when does it change?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the amount checker value to go to `onCreate` function

Since you need the `amount_checker` value inside a click listener of a button (and not when the `onCreate` method is called) you can make `amount_checker` a field of your `CartActivity` class.

Then you are just referencing `amount_checker` as `this.amount_checker` instead anywhere you need to read or assign the value (maybe in some scopes you might have to access it with `CartActivity.this.amount_checker`).

```
class CartActivity {
    // this stores the latest amount_checker value
    private double amount_checker = 0;

    private void calculateAmount() {  
       this.amount_checker = 1223.00023223; 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    buyItemButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (this.amount_checker >= 100){
                Intent intent = new Intent(CartActivity.this,AddressActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("itemList", (Serializable) itemsList);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+this.amount_checker, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });   
}
```